# Iterate string to compare an i element to i+1 element python

Tags: python, for-loop, string-iteration

I have a DNA sequence:

```
seq='AACGTTCAA'
```

I want to count how many letters are equal to the next one. In this example I should get 3 (because of AA-TT-AA).

In my first try I found out that this doesn't work, because i is a string and 1 an integer.

```
seq='AACGTTCAA'
count=[]
for i in seq:
    if i == i+1: #neither i+=1
        count.append(True)
    else: count.append(False)
print(sum(count))
```

So I tried this:

```
seq='AACGTTCAA'
count=[]
for i in seq:
    if i == seq[seq.index(i)+1]:
        count.append(True)
    else: count.append(False)
print(sum(count))
```

Then I receive this output which I cannot understand.
3 of these True should be False (1,5,8) Especially 8 as it is the last element of the string.

```
6
[True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True]
```

If thought about doing this with arrays but I think there might be a easy way to do this just in strings. Thanks

Comment: I think your index call always returns the first location of the character you're looking for, so that's why you're seeing too many `True`s ( [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) ) . I would do it as suggested in the answer by @bichanna below

Comment: What about `AAA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the statement for i in seq yields a series of string variables like 'A', 'A', 'C' etc.
so when in your first case when you are attempt to compare `i == i+1:` you are adding 1 to a string variable which throw a TypeError.
In your second example, where you execute `if i == seq[seq.index(i)+1]` gives a false result, since the seq.index(i) always returns the first occurrence of the value.
To do what you want on a basic level you can do the following:

```
def countPairedLetters(seq):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        # i starts with 1 and ends with len(seq)-1
        if seq[i-1] == seq[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Note: by starting with the index 1 and going to last, you avoid the issue with overrunning the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(seq)):
   if seq[i] == seq[i+1]: # <- this causes an error
      count.append(True)
```

Though you have to check if `seq[i+1]` does not cause an error.

**Update**

```
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(seq)-1): # this prevents an error
   if seq[i] == seq[i+1]:
      count += 1
```

Comment: The loop should run to `len(seq) - 1` to avoid overrun. Your current implementation will raise an error

Comment: Yes, that's right. I said so in the answer.

Comment: Also, keeping the count in a list won't help you get the count.

Comment: It's what the OP is doing. I just copied.

Comment: Instead of saying it, you should post code that isn't broken. If OP is doing the wrong thing, the whole point of answering is to correct them.

Comment: Okay. I'll update.

Comment: Please remove the broken code. It's better to add a line of prose explaining what you fixed. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools is one way:

```
from itertools import groupby
seq = 'AACGTTCAA'
print(sum(len(list(g))-1 for k,g in groupby(seq)))
```

This splits the sequence into groups of consecutive letters, then counts each group's lenght-1 into the total.

Edit: Updated with mozway's comments.

Comment: This won't work (AAAA would count as 1 instead of 3), you have to sum the len-1

Comment: You are correct, I did not realize this case from the example sequence. Updated the answer. It is not so pretty anymore but still a decent oneliner.

Comment: You just had to replace `>1` by `-1`, groups of 1 item would yield 0 ;)

Comment: Yes that's prettier although might be even more confusing to some. Let's do it :)

Comment: I don't think it's confusing, one just need to know how `groupby` works

Comment: Now it's beautiful ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for unwanted True's is because of seq.index()

index(), would always return the first occurrence of the character you are searching for. When you have 2 consecutive characters, its actually returning the index of the first occurrence of that character and they always match.

here is a quick solution:

```
seq='AACGTTCAA'
count=[]
for i in range(0,len(seq)-1):
    print(i)
    if seq[i]==seq[i+1]:
        count.append(True)
    else: count.append(False)
print(count)
```